# Angular - checkbox not maintaining model value

Tags: angular

I have a checkbox that I need the value to reflect the boolean in the data model and disregard attempts by the user to change it.

Here is an example of my setup:

Data model

```
const item = {label: 'test', active: false, selected: false};
```

Template with various inputs I have tried:

```
<li (click)="item.selected = !item.selected" [class.selected]="item.selected">
  <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="item.active">
  <input type="checkbox" [value]="item.active">
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="item.active">
  {{item.label}}
</li>
```

Since the active state in the data is not being changed (not 2 way bound) I would expect the checkbox to always remain in the un-checked state despite the user trying to check it.

This is not the case, however. The user can still check the box and the active state is still false, yet the selected state changes. What is preventing change detection from seeing that the checkbox DOM state is different than the model when that model has changed?

Does the change detection only watch the specific DOM elements and since the active state hasn't changed it assumes the DOM hasn't been affected?

How do I get change detection to see this change and utilize the model value accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `(click)="false"` in the `input` tag. That you stop the checkbox from toggling in the DOM.

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="item.active" (click)="false">{{item.label}}
```

Here's the Plunker [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/vEwFi4m8KRcPqnf3ROSM?p=preview).

Comment: This seems to work best for my use case without having to re-style anything. Thanks

Comment: Wierd hack, but it works! Thanks! Don't know why though.
I made a function that does some checks and returns false if the checkbox should not toggle, and it works!
I have a side-effect in this function, so I could not use [disabled].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just disabling the checkbox all together

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="item.active" disabled="true">
```